# How to unmute colors in SwiftUI's NavigationSplitView sidebar

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui-navigationsplitview, navigationsplitview

I am using `NavigationSplitView`, introduced in iOS16, with a basic list and attempting to color a system image with standard colors. I am noticing that when the `navigationSplitViewStyle` is `.automatic` or `.prominentDetail` and the color scheme is dark, that the colors are muted. I have not been able to figure out how to not-mute them, and thus stick with the original color as it's used in light mode. I'm wondering if this is possible to override? Or is there a way to drop down to UIKit and override this odd behavior?

Here is an example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
      List {
        ForEach([1, 2, 3], id: \.self) { item in
          Button {
          } label: {
            HStack {
              Image(systemName: "sunset.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
              Text("Item \(item)")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 40))
            .padding()
          }
        }
      }
    } detail: {
      Text("Detailed Content")
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      ContentView()
        .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
      ContentView()
        .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
  }
}
```

And you can see the different in the color between schemes here:

[image: Dark color scheme, colors look muted]

[image: Light color scheme, colors look great]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant that in dark mode, the sun in the symbol is black and you want to keep it white, then you can achieve this by setting `symbolRenderingMode` modifier on the image to `.palette` and give it two colors, the green one as well as white using the `foregroundStyle` modifier.

```swift
Image(systemName: "sunset.circle.fill")
    .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
    .foregroundStyle(.white, .green)
```

Refer to the following session from WWDC 2021 for more about using rendering modes for SF Symbols in SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10349

If you want the colors to be exactly the same and don’t change. You can use UIKit’s colors or define your own custom colors that don’t support dark mode.

```swift
.foregroundStyle(.white, Color(uiColor: .green))
```

```swift
.foregroundStyle(.white, Color(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0))
```

See the Fixed Colors section in this link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors

Comment: I tried this in the above sample code and in dark mode the green color is still muted in the sidebar when in portrait.

Comment: @stanlemon I updated my answer to handle how to use a color that don’t change between light and dark mode.

Comment: Got it, so basically you can't use the system colors inside of the sidebar then it seems. I noticed using named colors also bypasses this. What puzzles me is that the detail area of the split view or even the `balanced` `navigationSplitViewStyle` doesn't utilize the muted color on the system colors.